# Concurrent file reading / writing far slower than single-threaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing

**I am writing a program which reads, parses, and writes large (~15Gb) text files in parallel. On a single thread, the program works very quickly, but there is a massive performance drop when I run it concurrently on several jobs (much more than to be expected from multithreading overhead).**

The main file-reading/writing function takes an **"SRA"** object, which has two corresponding files associated with it, and the amount of RAM to dedicate, in bytes, as input. The function then reads the files chunk-buffer-wise and writes two new files that omit "error" information. The two files correspond to one another, with the information therein order-dependent. Their structure is not super important, but they look like this:

```
@SRR1000000.1 cor
ATATTTACCGGGTTATTCGGATTAGTTTTGGGCCCCCC
+
FFFFF:::F:::F:::,FFFF:::::::FFFFF,,,,F
@SRR1000000.2 error
ATTTTTTTTTCCCCCCGGCGGCGCGGCTTCTCGGTTAA
+
FF:FF:::::F::F::,,,,,:FFFFF,,F,F:,FF:F
@SRR1000000.3
ATTTTTTTTTCCCCCCGGCGGCGCGGCTTCTCGGTTAA
+
FF:FF:::::F::F::,,,,,:FFFFF,,F,F:,FF:F
.
.
.
```

The "header", beginning with **"@"**, is associated with and identifies the next 3 lines of data, and the number after the **"."** denotes the order. Both files have these headers.

Below is the file reader, parser, writer function mentioned above:

```
// File read/parse/write function
// Takes SRA object, amount of RAM as input
// Reads objects associated files in chunks according to RAM
// Parses them to remove "errors" while writing to new files
void rem_unfix(SRA sra, long long int ram_b) {
  // Get in-file / out-file paths
  std::string inFile1Str(sra.get_sra_path_corr().first.c_str());
  std::string inFile2Str(sra.get_sra_path_corr().second.c_str());
  std::string outFile1Str(std::string(sra.get_sra_path_corr().first.replace_extension("fix.fq").c_str()));
  std::string outFile2Str(std::string(sra.get_sra_path_corr().second.replace_extension("fix.fq").c_str()));
  // Open streams for file processing
  std::ifstream inFile1(inFile1Str);
  std::ifstream inFile2(inFile2Str);
  std::ofstream outFile1(outFile1Str);
  std::ofstream outFile2(outFile2Str);

  // Get amount of RAM to dedicate to each file (bytes)
  long long int ram_b_per_file = ram_b / 2;

  // Allocate space on heap for the file buffers
  char * inFile1Data = new char[ram_b_per_file];
  char * inFile2Data = new char[ram_b_per_file];

  // Algorithmic pointer/size variables to aid in parsing
  std::streamsize s1;
  std::streamsize s2;

  char * currPos1;
  char * currPos2;
  char * nlPos1;
  char * nlPos2;
  char * nlPos1Prev;
  char * nlPos2Prev;
  char * writeStart1;
  char * writeStart2;
  char * writeEnd1;
  char * writeEnd2;
  char * inFile1L;
  char * inFile2L;

  // Strings to ensure ends of buffers are lined up before parsing
  std::string readMatch;
  std::string read;
  
  // Main loop processes files in RAM-determined chunks
  while (!inFile1.eof() || !inFile2.eof()) {
    // Fill buffers, count number of bytes read to account for
    // end-of-file condition
    inFile1.read(inFile1Data, ram_b_per_file);
    inFile2.read(inFile2Data, ram_b_per_file);

    s1 = inFile1.gcount();
    s2 = inFile2.gcount();

    currPos1 = inFile1Data;
    currPos2 = inFile2Data;
    nlPos1 = inFile1Data;
    nlPos2 = inFile2Data;
    writeStart1 = inFile1Data;
    writeStart2 = inFile2Data;

    inFile1L = inFile1Data + s1;
    inFile2L = inFile2Data + s2;

    // Line up the ends of the buffers / ifstreams so that all
    // information is "paired", or that there is no piece of
    // data in one buffer without its partner data in the other 
    if (!inFile1.eof() && !inFile2.eof()) {
      // Unget/unstream character-wise until one of the buffers/ifstreams
      // ends just before a header
      while ((inFile1.peek() != '@' && inFile1.peek() != '>') &&
             (inFile2.peek() != '@' && inFile2.peek() != '>')) {
        if (inFile1.peek() != '@' && inFile1.peek() != '>') {
          inFile1.unget();
          inFile1Data[s1 - 1] = '\0';
          s1--;
        }
        if (inFile2.peek() != '@' && inFile2.peek() != '>') {
          inFile2.unget();
          inFile2Data[s2 - 1] = '\0';
          s2--; 
        }
      }

      // If inFile1's buffer was was first to get into position
      // Get its header number, get inFile2's last header number.
      // Then unstream accordingly until the two buffers end at the
      // same data point in their files.
      if (inFile1.peek() == '@' || inFile1.peek() == '>') {
        inFile1.get();
        inFile1 >> readMatch;
        while (inFile1.peek() != '@' && inFile1.peek() != '>') {
          inFile1.unget();
        }
        while (inFile2.peek() != '@' && inFile2.peek() != '>') {
          inFile2.unget();
          inFile2Data[s2 - 1] = '\0';
          s2--;
        }
        inFile2.get();
        inFile2 >> read;
        while (inFile2.peek() != '@' && inFile2.peek() != '>') {
          inFile2.unget();
        }
        if (read > readMatch) {
          inFile2.unget();
          while (read.compare(readMatch) != 0) {
            while (inFile2.peek() != '@' && inFile2.peek() != '>') {
              inFile2.unget();
              inFile2Data[s2 - 1] = '\0';
              s2--;
            }
            inFile2.get();
            inFile2 >> read;
            while (inFile2.peek() != '@' && inFile2.peek() != '>') {
              inFile2.unget();
            }
            inFile2.unget();
            inFile2Data[s2 - 1] = '\0';
            s2--;
          }
          inFile2.get();
        }
        else if (read < readMatch) {
          inFile1.unget();
          while (read.compare(readMatch) != 0) {
            while (inFile1.peek() != '@' && inFile1.peek() != '>') {
              inFile1.unget();
              inFile1Data[s1 - 1] = '\0';
              s1--;
            }
            inFile1.get();
            inFile1 >> readMatch;
            while (inFile1.peek() != '@' && inFile1.peek() != '>') {
              inFile1.unget();
            }
            inFile1.unget();
            inFile1Data[s1 - 1] = '\0';
            s1--;
          }
          inFile1.get();
        }
        else {
          // Buffer in position -- do nothing
        }
      }
      // If inFile2's buffer was was first to get into position
      // Get its header number, get inFile1's last header number.
      // Then unstream accordingly until the two buffers end at the
      // same data point in their files.
      else {
        inFile2.get();
        inFile2 >> readMatch;
        while (inFile2.peek() != '@' && inFile2.peek() != '>') {
          inFile2.unget();
        }
        while (inFile1.peek() != '@' && inFile1.peek() != '>') {
          inFile1.unget();
          inFile1Data[s1 - 1] = '\0';
          s1--;
        }
        inFile1.get();
        inFile1 >> read;
        while (inFile1.peek() != '@' && inFile1.peek() != '>') {
          inFile1.unget();
        }
        if (read > readMatch) {
          inFile1.unget();
          while (read.compare(readMatch) != 0) {
            while (inFile1.peek() != '@' && inFile1.peek() != '>') {
              inFile1.unget();
              inFile1Data[s1 - 1] = '\0';
              s1--;
            }
            inFile1.get();
            inFile1 >> read;
            while (inFile1.peek() != '@' && inFile1.peek() != '>') {
              inFile1.unget();
            }
            inFile1.unget();
            inFile1Data[s1 - 1] = '\0';
            s1--;
          }
          inFile1.get();
        }
        else if (read < readMatch) {
          inFile2.unget();
          while (read.compare(readMatch) != 0) {
            while (inFile2.peek() != '@' && inFile2.peek() != '>') {
              inFile2.unget();
              inFile2Data[s2 - 1] = '\0';
              s2--;
            }
            inFile2.get();
            inFile2 >> readMatch;
            while (inFile2.peek() != '@' && inFile2.peek() != '>') {
              inFile2.unget();
            }
            inFile2.unget();
            inFile2Data[s2 - 1] = '\0';
            s2--;
          }
          inFile2.get();
        }
        else {
          // Buffer in position -- do nothing
        }
      }
    }

    // With buffers now aligned, parse them and write non-error
    // information into the new files
    while (nlPos1 != inFile1L && nlPos2 != inFile2L) {
      nlPos1Prev = nlPos1;
      nlPos2Prev = nlPos2;
      nlPos1 = std::find(nlPos1 + 1, inFile1L, '\n');
      nlPos2 = std::find(nlPos2 + 1, inFile2L, '\n');
      if (strncmp(nlPos1 - 5, "error", 5) == 0 ||
          strncmp(nlPos2 - 5, "error", 5) == 0) {
        writeEnd1 = nlPos1Prev;
        outFile1.write(writeStart1, writeEnd1 - writeStart1);
        writeEnd2 = nlPos2Prev;
        outFile2.write(writeStart2, writeEnd2 - writeStart2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          nlPos1 = std::find(nlPos1 + 1, inFile1L, '\n');
          nlPos2 = std::find(nlPos2 + 1, inFile2L, '\n');
        }
        writeStart1 = nlPos1;
        writeStart2 = nlPos2;
      }
    }
    outFile1.write(writeStart1, inFile1Data + s1 - writeStart1);
    outFile2.write(writeStart2, inFile2Data + s2 - writeStart2);
  }
  inFile1.close();
  inFile2.close();
  outFile1.close();
  outFile2.close();
}
```

The function, albeit a bit spaghetti-ish, works fine. I call it into concurrency with the below function, which leverages a **"threadPool"** object, for which the header, implementation files are at the bottom of the question:

```
// Concurrency function which starts parallel file-pair-processing
// jobs for each **"SRA"** object in its input vector.
void rem_unfix_bulk(std::vector<SRA> sras, int numThreads, int ram_gb) {

  long long int ram_b = stoi(ram_gb) * 1000000000;
  long long int ram_b_per_thread = ram_b / numThreads;

  // Instantiate thread pool with numThreads threads to handle jobs
  threadPool fileCorrPool;
  fileCorrPool.start(numThreads);
  // Add queue jobs to thread pool
  for (auto sra : sras) {
    if (fs::exists(sra.get_sra_path_corr_fix().first.c_str())) {
      continue;
    }
    fileCorrPool.queueJob([sra, ram_b_per_thread {rem_unfix_pe(sra, ram_b_per_thread);});
  }
  fileCorrPool.stop();
}
```

threadPool object header file (**thread_pool.h**):

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>

class threadPool {
  public:
    void start(int threadNum);
    void queueJob(const std::function<void()>& job);
    void stop();
    bool busy();

  private:
    void threadLoop();

    bool endProc = false;
    std::mutex queue_mutex;
    std::condition_variable mutex_condition;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::queue<std::function<void()>> jobs;
};
```

threadPool object implementation file (**thread_pool.cpp**):

```
#include "thread_pool.h"

void threadPool::start(int threadNum) {
  threads.resize(threadNum);
  for (int i = 0; i < threadNum; i++) {
    threads.at(i) = std::thread(&threadPool::threadLoop, this);
  }
}


void threadPool::threadLoop() {
  while (true) {
    std::function<void()> job;
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
      mutex_condition.wait(lock, [this] {
                           return (!jobs.empty() || endProc);
                           });
      if (jobs.empty() && endProc) {
        return;
      }
      job = jobs.front();
      jobs.pop();
    }
    job();
  }
}


void threadPool::queueJob(const std::function<void()>& job) {
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
    jobs.push(job);
  }
  mutex_condition.notify_one();
}


bool threadPool::busy() {
  bool poolBusy;
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
    poolBusy = jobs.empty();
  }
  return poolBusy;
}

void threadPool::stop() {
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
    endProc = true;
  }
  mutex_condition.notify_all();
  for (std::thread& t : threads) {
    t.join();
  }
  threads.clear();
}
```

Comment: It seems obvious that an operating system attempts to optimize its internal algorithms and caching for the most common use case: reading files sequentially. This kind of an approach takes a wrecking ball to these carefully-laid plans...

Comment: Are you reading / writing to a SSD? If it's a hard drive expect multiple parallel operations to be slower than a large sequential operation.

Comment: I/O is very slow, and I/O bottlenecks arise because of device and hardware limits.  You cannot overcome those limits simply by making more requests per unit time, but you *can* issue requests that reduce each other's efficiency.

Comment: Assuming you have one drive, now rather than suffering the slow of reading from one drive you also have to suffer the slow of multiple threads fighting over the one drive.

Comment: A lot of things can happens. The thing is we cannot run this (pretty large) code and we have no idea of the target hardware so it is hard to know what could exactly going on. *Profiling* is the key to get some additional hint that can help you/us. Is the process IO bound ? RAM bound ? Fully compute bound ? Is the cache flushed since there is not enough memory ? Is the swap used ? Is there a race condition somewhere ? Is there some contention (eg allocators). Which part of the code should we focus ? etc.